# How to loop over nested JSON array and filter out search Query in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a complex nested JSON Array and I want to filter it(name property) through based on what user enters in input tag and show it as an autocomplete. A basic of it I have created here on stackblitz [click here for the code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-abrzsn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts). I have two entries of name "**Tom**" in two different objects so when user types **Tom** it should appear twice in the autocomplete as of now it shows only once. So if I press letter "T" it should show me all the names starting with "T". Here in this case **"Tom"** twice if I press "**To**" and if I press just "**T**" then Tiffany and Tom 2 times. Could you please help me here in the code ?
Any help is appreciated.  Thanks much!

Comment: Hi, would suggest you **paste minimal code snippet in the question** instead of only sharing the link. The link may potentially be broken, so your question cannot be reproduced and is not helpful for future reference. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the below code also, I have updated code you check in stackbliz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-k14se7

```
matches = [];
  ngOnInit() {}
  searchKeyup(ev) {
 
    var term: any = ev.target as HTMLElement;
    console.log("Value", term.value);
    this.matches = [];
    let content = [
      {
        name: 'Robert',
        children: [],
      },
      {
        name: 'Doug',
        children: [
          {
            name: 'James',
            children: [
              {
                name: 'John',
                children: [
                  {
                    name: 'Tom',
                    children: [],
                  },
                ],
              },
            ],
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        name: 'Susan',
        children: [
          {
            name: 'Tiffany',
            children: [
              {
                name: 'Merry',
                children: [
                  {
                    name: 'Sasha',
                    children: [],
                  },
                  {
                    name: 'Tommy',
                    children: [],
                  },
                ],
              },
            ],
          },
        ],
      },
    ];
    if(term.value.length > 0){
      this.filter(content, term.value);
    } else {
      document.getElementById('list').innerHTML = '';
    }

    if (this.matches.length > 0) {
      document.getElementById('list').innerHTML = this.matches.map(match => match.name).join(",");
    } else{
      document.getElementById('list').innerHTML = "";
    }
    
  }
  filter(arr, term) {
       
    arr.forEach((i) => {
      if (i.name.includes(term)) {
        this.matches.push(i);
      } 
      if (i.children.length > 0) {
        this.filter(i.children, term);
      }
    });
    console.log(this.matches);
  }
```

Comment: how about creating li tag before appending to list ?

Answer (score 0):

You were on a good path. The only missing thing in this recursive walk is keeping state of `matches` like this:

```js
filter(arr, term, matches) {
    if (term.length == 0) {
      matches = [];
      document.getElementById('list').innerHTML = '';
    }
    arr.forEach((i) => {
      if (i.name.includes(term)) {
        matches.push(i);
      } 
      if (i.children.length > 0) {
        this.filter(i.children, term, matches);
      }
    });
    console.log(matches);

    if (matches.length > 0) {
      document.getElementById('list').innerHTML = matches[0].name;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. So what needs to be done here ?

Comment: Just compare it with your filter() function. You can replace it in your code and see how it works. I hope it's what you are after